# Can obfuscated code for Flutter package or Flutter plugin

Tags: flutter

this [doc](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/obfuscate) shows how to obfuscate the flutter app. But in my case, I write a flutter package, and I don't want to provider its source code while other flutter app using this package, just like an android app using .aar as dependency. I cound not find relative doc for this situation.

[flutter/issues/98633](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/98633)

Answer (score 3):

The short answer seems to be that no, there is no simple way to achieve this. Take a look at [this Github issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/42863#issuecomment-665115458) where someone asks a similar question and it is explained that no built-in way exists to achieve this, though some suggestions are given that might be worth exploring.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official way of doing this. It only works on apps as of wrote comment.

This is the script i found on github that might help you

https://github.com/BankingofThings/dart-obfuscator

Remember to keep backup just in case

You can also do it manually but its tendinous work

Comment: could you demonstrate an example of it ?.Obfuscating the code and then importing the package for using the exposed method.