# Is code obfuscation possible in a Flutter package (released in pub.dev)

Tags: flutter, pub.dev

I want to know if code obfuscation is possible as I have some logics which I want to hide when we re release our SDK in pub.dev

I could not find a way to do it. I refered the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to the official documentation https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/obfuscate

```
flutter build apk --obfuscate --split-debug-info=/<project-name>/<directory>
```

It looks like obfuscating a package is not possible [Can obfuscated code for Flutter package or Flutter plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71151818/can-obfuscated-code-for-flutter-package-or-flutter-plugin)

Answer (score 1):

It isn't allowed nor possible to obfuscate packages for pub.dev.

It is supposed to be open source there, by its rules.